# jQuery UI error: TypeError: this._addClass is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui

I try to use jQuery UI in a Wordpress theme for a dialog popup.

```
$( function() {
$( "#info" ).dialog();
```

});

When I enter the code like that, I get the following error in the console:
TypeError: this._addClass is not a function

I don't have any clue what is wrong. Can anybody give me a hint?

cheers
Dan

Comment: tried that, but still have the same issue.

Comment: ok, i forgot to add the document ready statement.

Comment: Change jQueryUI to version 1.11.4 and make sure jQuery is not added twice.